# Need regular expression to close or replace quotes

Tags: c#, regex

Please help me solve my problem.
I have a list of following strings:

```
a
"b
c"
"ddd"
'ee'
a"b"c
a'b'c
```

as a result I need:

```
"a"
"b"
"c"
"ddd"
"ee"
"a\"b\"c"
"a'b'c"
```

Please help me write pattern for replace.

Comment: KISS. Trim the 'ends'. Then do a simply string.Replace for `"`. Finally wrap it in `"..."`.

Comment: Does it have to be RegEx? Looks like it is simple enough to do with regular string operations.

Comment: Too slow @Oded ;P (all 13 seconds of it)

Comment: @leppie - I need to work on my touch typing ;)

Comment: @Oded: I can't touch type :)  (have to always look at keyboard :( )

Comment: @Dimitriy why are you so keen to do this as a regex ? It's slower and more complicated than needed.

Comment: I've got a question about the "spec" (please pity me!)... Since you apparently need to escape double-quotes with backslashes, will you need to do anything with backslashes that are already in the string? Or do you simply leave them as is, which is relatively unconventional?

Comment: @Toader Mihai Claudiu, Because  RegEx is the Holy Grail of programming, giving the programmer a b*ner instantly on the mere thought of using it. ;)

Answer (score 3):

As others have already noted in comments, too: This isn't a job for regular expressions. In fact, if you try to do so you'll get code that is *less* readable and maintanable than the straightforward idea.

```
string.Concat("\"", myString.Trim('"', '\'').Replace("\"","\\\""), "\"");
```

PowerShell test:

```
PS Home:\> filter fixString { '"' + $_.Trim('"', "'").Replace('"', '\"') + '"' }
PS Home:\> 'a','"b','c"','"ddd"',"'ee'",'a"b"c',"a'b'c" | fixString
"a"
"b"
"c"
"ddd"
"ee"
"a\"b\"c"
"a'b'c"
```

However, if you desperately need regular expressions, I can think of only the following three individual replacements:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"^['""]|['""]$", "");
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"""", @"\""");
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, "^|$", @"""");
```

PowerShell test:

```
PS Home:\> 'a','"b','c"','"ddd"',"'ee'",'a"b"c',"a'b'c" |
>> % { $_ -replace '^[''"]|[''"]$' -replace '"','\"' -replace '^|$','"' }
"a"
"b"
"c"
"ddd"
"ee"
"a\"b\"c"
"a'b'c"
```

The following works with only two regular expressions, thanks to [Toader Mihai Claudiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106463/toader-mihai-claudiu) who offered some crucial advice:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(@"^['""]?(.*?)['""]?$", @"""$1""");
myString = Regex.Replace(@"(?<=.)""(?=.)", @"\""");
```

PowerShell test:

```
PS Home:\> 'a','"b','c"','"ddd"',"'ee'",'a"b"c',"a'b'c" |
>> % { $_ -replace '^[''"]?(.*?)[''"]?$','"$1"' -replace '(?<=.)"(?=.)','\"' }
"a"
"b"
"c"
"ddd"
"ee"
"a\"b\"c"
"a'b'c"
```

Now ask yourself: Would you still know what the code does in a month from now? A year maybe?

Comment: THanks, so about regex pattern?

Comment: @Dmitriy: Why regular expressions? Why are you so insistant on a specific tool that's not even very useful in this case?

Comment: yep .. you can't do it in one anyway :(

Comment: @Toader: I tried getting it down to two (where the one that removes starting and ending quotes will also prepend and append a quote, but for some reason the trailing one will not be removed: `$_ -replace '^[''"]?|[''"]?$','"' -replace '(?<=.)"(?=.)','\"'`

Comment: @joey try this `^[''"]?(.*)[''"]?$"` and replace with `"$1"` :)

Comment: @Toader: Ah, thanks. The sins from the early days of regex still work, a bit at least. It brought me on the right track :-)

Comment: @joey Yep ... happens to me too sometimes :.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the C# syntax, but I think you should split it in three easy steps.

For each string:
  - Strip start and end quote if any.
  - Escape the string.
  - Add start and end quote.

Should be easy to implement.

Comment: @Dmitriy - that doesn't make sense. This isn't validation - a regex replace is a line on C# code anyway (unless you're restricted by a weird library). Why must it be a regex? Also, I doubt you'll find a single regex that does all replaces for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it manually. Add a " in a buffer, skip the first char in the string if `"` or `'` add each non `"` as it is to the buffer and quote every `"` (aka convert it to `\"`). And at the end (don't add quoted `"` until you have a next char that is different than `"`) just add a non quoted `"` if the last char is `"` or `'`.

You can do this with maybe 2 regex search and replace but it's more efficient to do it as above.